laravel 11_ Backback
I have an issue where I uploaded my Laravel 11 project to InfinityFree hosting and used Backpack to create a dashboard for managing my website. However, when I navigate to the admin panel link, and after successfully logging in, I try to view the data stored in the database, but I encounter a 419 Page Expired error.
I have tried many solutions without success. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
Note: I also tried disabling CSRF verification, but that did not work either.
disabling CSRF verification.
I tried searching for solutions online and implementing suggestions.
I have checked Laravel's and Backpack's configurations, session settings, or routes.
I  expected the 419 error to stop appearing.

It seems like this could be a session-related issue. How is your session configured in the .env file? If the session driver is set to "file", make sure the correct permissions are applied to the storage directory. You can set them using the following command:
chmod -R 775 storage

Also, ensure the correct owner and group are assigned to the directory.
For Backpack, it's crucial to have the APP_URL setting in your .env file configured correctly. Verify that it matches the URL you use to access your application.
After making these adjustments, clear and optimize your application's cache by running the following commands:
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan basset:clear
php artisan optimize

If the issue persists, check the Laravel error logs (storage/logs/laravel.log) or your server's logs for more details.
Cheers!

I tried these methods but to no avail. Thanks for your help.

This happens because the APP_URL in the .env file is not correctly set.
Make sure the APP_URL in your .env file is correctly pointing to the URL you use to access your application in the browser, for example http://something.test
If you are using php artisan serve to serve your application in http://127.0.0.1:8000, that's what you need to write in APP_URL.
If you are using https, make sure you write it down in app url.
Let me know if that solves the issue for you.

While searching for a solution to this problem, I found your suggestion as one of these solutions, but it did not work. The problem is that this problem only appears on the hosting, but on the local server it works properly.
